# Teradata - What is wrong with this query? "Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group."

Tags: sql, aggregate, teradata

I am currently working on an sql problem using teradata, but I keep getting the error message although I can't find any problems.
Here is my query :

```
SELECT TOP 10 d.deptdesc, tt.store, SUM(tt.amt11) AS sum11, SUM(tt.amt12) AS sum12,
        SUM(tt.num11) AS num11, SUM(tt.num12) AS num12,
        sum11/num11 AS avg11, sum12/num12 AS avg12,
        (avg12-avg11)/avg11 * 100 AS increase
FROM(SELECT store, 
        SUM(CASE monthId WHEN 11 THEN total_revenue END) AS amt11,
        SUM(CASE monthId WHEN 12 THEN total_revenue END) AS amt12,
        SUM(CASE monthId WHEN 11 THEN date_num END) AS num11,
        SUM(CASE monthId WHEN 12 THEN date_num END) AS num12
    FROM(SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) AS monthId,
                EXTRACT(YEAR FROM saledate) AS yearId,
                store,
                SUM(amt) AS total_revenue,
                COUNT(DISTINCT saledate) AS date_num       
            FROM trnsact
            WHERE stype = 'P' AND NOT(monthId = '8' AND yearId = '2005') 
            GROUP BY monthId, yearId, store
            HAVING date_num >= 20) t
    GROUP BY store) tt 
INNER JOIN (SELECT sku, store FROM trnsact) ttt ON tt.store = ttt.store 
INNER JOIN skuinfo sku ON ttt.sku = sku.sku
INNER JOIN deptinfo d ON sku.dept = d.dept
GROUP BY d.deptdesc, tt.store
HAVING sum11 > 1000 AND sum12 > 1000
ORDER BY increase DESC;
```

Teradata gives out the message like this

> Error Code - 3504 
>   Error Message - [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.05] [Error 3504] [SQLState HY000] Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.

Could you give me any advice?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `avg11` and `avg12` too `increase` should appears in last `group by`

Comment: "Error Code - 3625 
Error Message - [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.05] [Error 3625] [SQLState HY000] GROUP BY and WITH...BY clauses may not contain aggregate functions."  still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser check for non aggregated column you alias  for aggregated  but the 
You could not use alias for select column directly in select  so  you should use :

```
SELECT TOP 10 
  d.deptdesc
  , tt.store
  , SUM(tt.amt11) AS sum11
  , SUM(tt.amt12) AS sum12
  , SUM(tt.num11) AS num11
  , SUM(tt.num12) AS num12
  , SUM(tt.amt11)/SUM(tt.num11) AS avg11
  , SUM(tt.amt12)/SUM(tt.num12) AS avg12
  , (SUM(tt.amt12)/SUM(tt.num12)-SUM(tt.amt11)/SUM(tt.num11))/SUM(tt.amt11)/SUM(tt.num11) * 100 AS increase
  ....
```

Comment: @MichelleRainbelt  You have asked  for an error  .. and as you tell me the error is gone  ..  if the query return a result that you like or not is not a question  ..so you should recognize that my answer is correct and therefore mark it as accepted .. and other issues you should post them as new questions

Comment: Oops no offense! I just found it frustrating that the result is not like the answer 'even though' the query is corrected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MichelleRainbelt: Well, in fact you *can* use an alias in any place in Teradata (which breaks all the rules of Standard SQL, but is *really* nice). But the parser searches for a column in the list of existing columns first and only if it's not found in the alias list. Thus your problem is an alias like `SUM(tt.num11) AS num11`, in `sum11/num11` the 1st `sum11` is fine, but the 2nd `num11` resolves to `tt.num11`, not the sum. Basic rule: *never assign an alias name which already exists as a column name, when you want to use it*

Comment: @MichelleRainbelt  no offense .. sure  .. the suggestion for a new questio is for let a clear approach to the problem without changin  "on the way" that make all so complicated ... then when you have posted  the new question with  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. you can comment me the related  link so i can take a loo k ..  anyway  .. thanks  ..

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for your detailed explanation. Now everything seems clear!

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT TOP 10  deptdesc, store, sum11, sum12, num11, num12,
            sum11/num11 AS avg11, sum12/num12 AS avg12,
            ((sum12/num12)-(sum11/num11))/(sum11/num11)* 100 AS increase FROM
(
    SELECT d.deptdesc, tt.store, SUM(tt.amt11) AS sum11, SUM(tt.amt12) AS sum12,
            SUM(tt.num11) AS num11, SUM(tt.num12) AS num12
    FROM(SELECT store, 
            SUM(CASE monthId WHEN 11 THEN total_revenue END) AS amt11,
            SUM(CASE monthId WHEN 12 THEN total_revenue END) AS amt12,
            SUM(CASE monthId WHEN 11 THEN date_num END) AS num11,
            SUM(CASE monthId WHEN 12 THEN date_num END) AS num12
        FROM(SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM saledate) AS monthId,
                    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM saledate) AS yearId,
                    store,
                    SUM(amt) AS total_revenue,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT saledate) AS date_num       
                FROM trnsact
                WHERE stype = 'P' AND NOT(monthId = '8' AND yearId = '2005') 
                GROUP BY monthId, yearId, store
                HAVING date_num >= 20) t
        GROUP BY store) tt 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT sku, store FROM trnsact) ttt ON tt.store = ttt.store 
    INNER JOIN skuinfo sku ON ttt.sku = sku.sku
    INNER JOIN deptinfo d ON sku.dept = d.dept
    GROUP BY d.deptdesc, tt.store
) AS T
    GROUP BY deptdesc, tt.store, sum11, sum12, num11, num12
    HAVING sum11 > 1000 AND sum12 > 1000
    ORDER BY increase DESC;
```

Comment: Now sends out a different error message..  "Error Occurred . . .
[com.teradata.commons.datatools.sqlparsers.common.ParseException: Encountered "GROUP" at line 28, column 5. Was expecting one of: "as" ... <NAME> ... ]"

Comment: "Error Occurred . . .
[com.teradata.commons.datatools.sqlparsers.common.ParseException: Encountered "GROUP" at line 28, column 5. Was expecting one of: "as" ... <NAME> ... ]" Hmm still doesn't seem right...

Comment: @MichelleRainbelt my query resolve your problem i try solve your secondary problem to complete your query

Comment: Teradata needs an alias for the Derived Table (afaik only in Oracle it's optional), simply add it after the final `)`, e.g. `) as dt`